# Control trim seek bar in UIImagePickerController with Source type camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

In my application i need to allow the user to record the video without any time limit (only while recording), but after recording in the edit view, i need to control the trim seek bar up to 30 sec (meaning user can use only the 30 secs video alone from the recorded full length video).

Here is my code to present the picker controller:

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.delegate = (id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>) self;
[self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
```

if we set the video maximum duration is 30 sec means we cant record after 30 sec it will break my functionality.

my question is, is it possible to control the trim seek bar with out the knowledge of maximum duration property

or

is it possible to alert the user based on the video current trim length status while trimming?

Please guide me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to implement your own trimming solution.

See:
https://github.com/andrei200287/SAVideoRangeSlider